# Construct a CW complex with prescribed homotopy groups and actions of $\pi_1$.

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

How to construct a CW complex $X$ with prescribed homotopy groups $\pi_i(X)$ and prescribed actions of $\pi_1(X)$ on the $\pi_i(X)$'s?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One method is as follows.

1. Construct $Y_i = K(\pi_i, i)$ for $i \geq 2$ as a based space with an action of the group $\pi_1$.  You can do this manually (by attaching free orbits of cells along the group action) or canonically (using a functorial construction of Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces, such as one obtained from the Dold-Kan correspondence and geometric realization).
2. Take $Y = \prod_{i \geq 2} Y_i$ as a based space with the correct "top" homotopy groups and an action of $\pi_1$ realizing the desired action on the higher homotopy groups.
3. Take the Borel construction $X = E\pi_1 \times_{\pi_1} Y$.  This space, by construction, has fundamental group $\pi_1$, has $E \pi_1 \times Y \simeq Y$ as universal cover, and has the group of deck transformations  given by the action of $\pi_1$ on $E\pi_1 \times Y$.

Of course, you don't *have* to take $Y$ to be a product of Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces.  Passing between universal covers and Borel constructions reduced your original question to finding a simply-connected space with the given higher homotopy groups and an action of $\pi_1$ on the whole space.

You might also specify more structure; for example, the higher homotopy groups in the outlined construction are not related by Whitehead products or anything similar.  This makes the problem harder.  If you specify *all* the structure that the homotopy groups naturally have, you have a so-called $\Pi$-algebra; the paper "[The realization space of a $\Pi$-algebra](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/cgi-bin/generate?/Blanc-Dwyer-Goerss/moduli)" by Blanc-Dwyer-Goerss studies this problem and how one might go about classifying realizations.

Comment: Is the space with prescribed homotopy groups and actions of fundamental group unique in the homotopy category? If not, is there a way to make it unique by adding suitable condition?

Comment: @Lao-tzu It is most definitely not. If you know that the space is a topological abelian group, then you do get uniqueness, but there are not many other cases that I can think of where this is true.